# Compute the laplacian of the distance function in radial coordinates.

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Let $M$ be a $n$-dimensional Riemannian manifold with metric $g$ in radial coordinates
$$g=dr^2 + r^2 g_{ij} d\theta_i d\theta_j$$
then
$$\Delta r = \frac{n-1}{r} + \frac{\partial}{\partial r} \log \sqrt{G}$$
where $G=\sqrt{\det g_{ij}}$ for $1\leq i,j\leq n-1$.

I am unsure how to prove this identity using the definition of the Hessian, so any comments/suggestions will be much appreciated.

Comment: Google the Voss-Weyl formula. It tells you that $\Delta_g f=\frac{1}{\sqrt{|g|}}\frac{\partial}{\partial x^a}\left(\sqrt{|g|}g^{ab}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^b}\right)$ (this holds for any non-degenerate $g$).

Comment: oops, i should have thought of that before! Thank you very much!